# How can I print definition of a symbol without evaluation in Scheme?

Tags: printing, scheme, symbols

If I want to print function definition for a symbol, what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a function `print-function` such that after

```
(define (foo x) (cons x x))
```

it will behave as

```
> (print-function foo)
(lambda (x) (cons x x))
```

Standard Scheme doesn't have a facility for that. The reason is Scheme implementations may, and generally do, compile functions into a different representation (bytecode, machine code).

Some Schemes may keep the function definition around; check your implementation's manual.

Comment: Guile versions before 2.0 had `procedure-source`. Since Guile 2.0, however, I've never managed to get `procedure-source` to work any more. But yeah, it's very implementation-specific, and most implementations don't provide any such thing.

Comment: I'm using Gambit-C. Do you know about this on the implementation?

Comment: No experience with Gambit, sorry.

Comment: There's [a bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?30469) for `procedure-source` open since Guile 1.9.11.